# Testing issue with passing parameter into method

Tags: apex, unit-test

How can I pass values into the below for testing:

```
public Boolean process(deal__c[] deals, contractPrototype cp, Enmax_Quote__c[] quotes, contractV2__c newContract)
```

Testclass:

```
ProcessPrice controller = new ProcessPrice();
controller.process(d1.id,null,null,null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your signature is:

- Deal__c[]
- contractPrototype
- Enmax_Quote__c
- contractV2__c

So you need to meet that criteria

Your first parameter is an `ID` and that is not the correct type for `Deal__c[]`

Change to

```
 ProcessPrice controller = new ProcessPrice(); 
 controller.process(New Deals__c[]{d1},null,null,null);
```

Comment: How can we pass value for contractV2__c

Comment: Replace the last null with an instance of `contractV2__c`

Comment: contractPrototype is an entire class so an instance of this well will work??

Comment: @Ankita - Yup. Since you are new wanted to point out that  if questions help upvoting is encouraged and if a question solves your issue common etiquette is to mark it as accepted so other searching for answer to a similar issue can find them